# How to prevent blank xmlns attributes in output from .NET's XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-namespaces, xmldocument

When generating XML from XmlDocument in .NET, a blank `xmlns` attribute appears the first time an element *without* an associated namespace is inserted; how can this be prevented?

Example:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.AppendChild(xml.CreateElement("root",
    "whatever:name-space-1.0"));
xml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xml.CreateElement("loner"));
Console.WriteLine(xml.OuterXml);
```

Output:

```
<root xmlns="whatever:name-space-1.0"><loner xmlns="" /></root>
```

*Desired* Output:

```
<root xmlns="whatever:name-space-1.0"><loner /></root>
```

Is there a solution applicable to the `XmlDocument` code, not something that occurs *after* converting the document to a string with `OuterXml`?

My reasoning for doing this is to see if I can match the standard XML of a particular protocol using XmlDocument-generated XML.  The blank `xmlns` attribute *may* not break or confuse a parser, but it's also not present in any usage that I've seen of this protocol.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Thanks to Jeremy Lew's answer and a bit more playing around, I figured out how to remove blank `xmlns` attributes: pass in the root node's namespace when creating any child node you want *not* to have a prefix on.  Using a namespace without a prefix at the root means that you need to use that same namespace on child elements for them to *also* not have prefixes.

Fixed Code:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.AppendChild(xml.CreateElement("root", "whatever:name-space-1.0"));
xml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xml.CreateElement("loner", "whatever:name-space-1.0")); 
Console.WriteLine(xml.OuterXml);
```

Thanks everyone to all your answers which led me in the right direction!

Comment: Precisely. Putting the <loner> element in the "whatever:name-space-1.0" namespace means that the empty xmlns attribute (which puts it in no namespace) won't be added to it when it's serialised. If you need refreshing on how namespaces work, have a look at http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm

Comment: Watch out: Elements need this (or the perhaps better `doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI`) but don't specify a namespace for `CreateAttribute()` of you'll get the `xmlns:psomething` even if it is the same uri.

Answer (score 98):

This is a variant of JeniT's answer (Thank you very very much btw!)

```
XmlElement new_element = doc.CreateElement("Foo", doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
```

This eliminates having to copy or repeat the namespace everywhere.

Comment: Best response according to me. We don't have to know what is document default namespace (usefull when we don't create a xml file from scratch ie in read and modify scenarios).

Answer (score 12):

If the `<loner>` element in your sample XML didn't have the `xmlns` default namespace declaration on it, then it would be in the `whatever:name-space-1.0` namespace rather than being in no namespace. If that's what you want, you need to create the element in that namespace:

```
xml.CreateElement("loner", "whatever:name-space-1.0")
```

If you want the `<loner>` element to be in no namespace, then the XML that's been produced is exactly what you need, and you shouldn't worry about the `xmlns` attribute that's been added automatically for you.

Comment: The problem lies with non-compliant XML parsers (typically from Microsoft) that can't cope with xmnls="").

Comment: /. called.  They want their random MS bashing comment back.

Comment: @W. Craig Trader - can't say I've encountered that as a problem. Example?

Comment: Correct, I do not want the <loner /> node to have a namespace, but I don't want it to have a blank namespace attribute (xmlns) either.  My reasoning is just to see if I can match the XML output of a particular protocol which is setup like this.

Comment: It wasn't random bashing.  The Microsoft Updater Application Block uses an XML Manifest to determine what to deliver to a client.  Unfortunately, the Manifest parser can't cope with xmlns=""; I had to write a post-processor that would strip out the empty xmlns attributes.

Answer (score 7):

Since root is in an unprefixed namespace, any child of root that wants to be un-namespaced has to be output like your example.  The solution would be to prefix the root element like so:

```
<w:root xmlns:w="whatever:name-space-1.0">
   <loner/>
</w:root>
```

code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement( "w", "root", "whatever:name-space-1.0" );
doc.AppendChild( root );
root.AppendChild( doc.CreateElement( "loner" ) );
Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);
```

Comment: Thanks, but adding the namespace to the actual root would break my XML in relation to the particular protocol I'm working with.

Comment: Ah!  I realized more what you were saying and took it into account when writing my own answer.  Thanks Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

If possible, create a serialization class then do:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("", "");
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(yourType);
serializer.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, someObject, ns);
```

It's safer, and you can control the namespaces with attributes if you really need more control.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by using the Factory Pattern. I created a factory for XElement objects. As parameter for the instantiation of the factory I've specified a XNamespace object. So, everytime a XElement is created by the factory the namespace will be added automatically. Here is the code of the factory:

```
internal class XElementFactory
{
    private readonly XNamespace currentNs;

    public XElementFactory(XNamespace ns)
    {
        this.currentNs = ns;
    }

    internal XElement CreateXElement(String name, params object[] content)
    {
        return new XElement(currentNs + name, content);
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP was asking about `XmlDocument`, not `XDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can prevent the XMLNS from the XmlElement .
First Creating time it is coming : like that

```
<trkpt lat="30.53597" lon="-97.753324" xmlns="">
    <ele>249.118774</ele>
    <time>2006-05-05T14:34:44Z</time>
</trkpt>
```

Change the code : And pass xml namespace
like this

C# code:

```
XmlElement bookElement = xdoc.CreateElement("trkpt", "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1");
bookElement.SetAttribute("lat", "30.53597");
bookElement.SetAttribute("lon", "97.753324");
```