# Unwanted xmlns="" in _di_IXMLNode

Tags: c++, xml, c++builder, xmldocument

I'm creating a xml-file for display in Excel using _di_IXMLDocument. But for some tags I get an unwanted extra (empty) xmlns attribute witch makes the file unreadable for Excel...
This is what i do:

```
...
_di_IXMLNode worksheet = workbook->AddChild("Worksheet");
worksheet->SetAttribute("ss:Name",Now().DateString());
...
```

and this is what comes out:

```
<Worksheet xmlns="" ss:Name="2008-12-11">
```

Where does xmlns come from? How do I get rid of it?

EDIT:
Some more info: If I try to add a xmlns attribute to Worksheet myself, like this:

```
...
_di_IXMLNode worksheet = workbook->AddChild("Worksheet");
worksheet->SetAttribute("xlmns","Foo");
worksheet->SetAttribute("ss:Name",Now().DateString());
...
```

Then the child nodes of "Worksheet" all get the empty xmlns attributes instead!

```
<Worksheet xmlns="Foo" ss:Name="2008-12-11">
  <Table xmlns="">
```

Comment: I tried to fix the tag, but it seems SO is broken in that respect :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135000/how-to-prevent-blank-xmlns-attributes-in-output-from-nets-xmldocument) question. The trick was to create the child nodes and telling the what namespace they belong to, and then not to output it...

```
_di_IXMLNode worksheet = workbook->AddChild("Worksheet","workbooks-namespace",false);
worksheet->SetAttribute("ss:Name",Now().DateString());
```

this produces the desired output:

```
<Worksheet ss:Name="2008-12-11">
```

Answer (score 1):

xmlns stands for xml name space, if an attribute does not receive an explicit name space, it possesses none.

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/