# Why does .NET XML append an xlmns attribute to XmlElements I add to a document? Can I stop it?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, mono

I am adding XmlElement to an existing document but an extra attribute is being added. Here is the code:

```
XmlNode manifest = this.getManifestNode ();
XmlElement manifestEntry = _content.CreateElement ("item", _contentPath);
XmlAttribute id = _content.CreateAttribute ("id"); 
id.Value = "content" + getManifestNodes ().Count;
XmlAttribute href = _content.CreateAttribute ("href"); 
href.Value = splitPath [splitPath.Length - 1]; 
XmlAttribute mediaType = _content.CreateAttribute ("media-type"); 
mediaType.Value = "application/xhtml+xml"; 
manifestEntry.Attributes.Append (id); 
manifestEntry.Attributes.Append (href); 
manifestEntry.Attributes.Append (mediaType); 
manifest.AppendChild (manifestEntry);
```

and the resulting XML:

```
<item id="content3" href="test1.html" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" xmlns="/home/jdphenix/epubtest/test/OEBPS/content.opf" />
```

Where is the

```
xmlns="/home/jdphenix/epubtest/test/OEBPS/content.opf"
```

coming from? The path that it adds is the location of the document on disk, but I'm not adding it in my code (atleast, that I am aware of). Let me know if you need to know more details.

Edit: I modified my code per Filburt's suggestion and changed

```
XmlElement manifestEntry = _content.CreateElement ("item", _contentPath);
```

to

```
XmlElement manifestEntry = _content.CreateElement ("item");
```

This is a step in the right direction, but produces the following XML:

```
<item id="content3" href="test1.html" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" xmlns="" />
```

Comment: My problem with the blank xmlns attribute is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135000/how-to-prevent-blank-xmlns-attributes-in-output-from-nets-xmldocument, looking into it now

Comment: This happens because .NET's Xml classes treat xmlns properly. This "problem" was caused by my lack of understanding of XML namespaces. 

The output was producing a blank xmlns attribute entry because it was told to do so by the call to 

    XmlElement manifestEntry = _content.CreateElement ("item");

instead of 

    XmlElement manifestEntry = _content.CreateElement ("item", "http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf");

I did not provide details in my original question to properly answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135000/how-to-prevent-blank-xmlns-attributes-in-output-from-nets-xmldocument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding this namespace yourself (Line 2):

```
XmlElement manifestEntry = _content.CreateElement ("item", _contentPath);
```

See [XmlDocument.CreateElement Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1k08cbx.aspx) - the first String parameter is the qualified name of the element you are adding and the second string is the namespace.

Try

```
XmlElement manifestEntry = _content.CreateElement ("item");
```

and everything should be fine.