# Write NameSpaces in XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, xml-namespaces

I need to generate an XML file using C# class (XmlDocument or XDocument) with the following root element:

```
<ns1:ConsultaSeqRps xmlns:ns1="http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/lote" 
    xmlns:tipos="http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/tp" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/lote http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/xsd/ConsultaSeqRps.xsd">
```

I've tried various alternatives using setAttribute and XmlNamespaceManager but without success.

Comment: Show the code you used so we can show you what you did wrong.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: See if this helps you - may or may not be unrelated - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450860/why-does-net-xml-append-an-xlmns-attribute-to-xmlelements-i-add-to-a-document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward, except maybe for the use of XAttribute to add a named namespace:

```
XNamespace ns1 = "http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/lote";
XNamespace tipos = "http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/tp";
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

var doc = new XElement(ns1 + "ConsultaSeqRps",
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ns1", ns1), 
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "tipos", tipos), 
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
    new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", 
      "http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/lote http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/xsd/ConsultaSeqRps.xsd")
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the advantage of LINQ to XML, the following article will help you to Create namespace in c# 
[How to: Create a Document with Namespaces (C#) (LINQ to XML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx)

Hope that help.

Regards