# Visual studio selectively build satellite dlls for language resource files based on configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, internationalization

got an interesting little problem that I can't seem to find an answer to on here.

My project in visual studio 2013 contains lots of language resource files Resources.en-GB.resx etc for the different languages that it can be used in.  They compile to dlls in bin\debug\en-GB\Projecty.Wojecty.resources.dll etc.

I also have different build configurations that change a few things for when in different countries.

My question is how do I only build certain language resource dlls for certain build configurations.  For example for a deployment in Russia I only want the russian and english language dlls. For deployment in Germany I only want german and english

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32323273/how-do-i-prevent-foreign-language-resource-generation-by-overriding-msbuild-targ/32326251#32326251). Please make sure to read Alexey Shcherbak's comments for a more compact alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jenszcz answer and Alexey Scherbaks comments I've discovered a whole new world of msbuild condition statements.  Edited the csproj file to add conditions to all the EmbeddedResources

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Localisation\Resources.en-GB.resx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' OR '$(Configuration)' == 'Germany' " Include="Localisation\Resources.de-DE.resx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' OR '$(Configuration)' == 'Russia' " Include="Localisation\Resources.ru-RU.resx" />
</ItemGroup>
```